# Best way to keep aggregate counts for event Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, time-series, pageviews

I have page view event data that is currently stored in Google Firestore that gets loaded automatically into a BigQuery dataset.  I am using this data to show total page counts and "trending" page counts (total views within last 48 hours).

I need to feed the total and trending page counts (grouped by page) to a database to use in the front-end website.  I have written BigQuery SQL to query the total counts, but I worry that these queries will become inefficient over time.

It seems that I should somehow pre-aggregate the counts in a table as the events come in (streaming).

What is the most efficient way to aggregate time series data like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [materialized views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro). They require minimum maintenance.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I’ll check it out.